# Проблема с доступом к админ панели wildfly

Tags: веб-сервер, jboss, wildfly

До недавнего времени админка wildfly запускалась без проблем, но сейчас, при обращении по http localhost:9990, вываливается панель "Connect to Management Interface", где представлен пустой список интерфейсов и возможность здесь же добавить какой-нибудь. К сожалению, не могу приложить скриншот.

Не совсем понятно, с чего вдруг меня не пускает в админку + что за интерфейс?

Пробовал добавить интерфейс со следующими параметрами:

- name: management
- Scheme: http
- Hostname: 127.0.0.1
- Port: 9990

, но выходит ошибка: "The management interface does not respond. Please make sure the interface is up and running and "http 127.0.0.1:9990" is configured as an allowed origin."

При этом я авторизован, сервер работает, в логах ничего криминального.

При обращении по http 127.0.0.1:9990/management получаю:

```
{
    «outcome» : «failed»,
    «failure-description» : «WFLYCTL0313: Unauthorized to execute operation ‘read-resource’ for resource ‘[]’ — \»WFLYCTL0332: Permission denied\»»,
    «rolled-back» : true
}
```

Comment: Переустановил сервер, проблема пропала. Тем не менее, в чем причина - пока не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема была в правах доступа. WildFly, в отличии от JBoss поддерживает 2 схемы обеспечения прав юзеров в админ панели:

- Simple - аналогичен JBoss. Любой админ имеет неограниченные права.
- RBAC (Role Based Access Control) - позволяет, соответственно, разграничить доступ в админку.

По умолчанию, при установке сервера параметр доступа устанавливается в Simple и находится здесь:

```
{wildfly}\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

{wildfly}\domain\configuration\domain.xml

<management>
  ...
    <access-control provider="simple">
        <role-mapping>
            <role name="SuperUser">
                <include>
                    <user name="$local"/>
                </include>
            </role>
        </role-mapping>
    </access-control>
</management>
```

Чтобы установить RBAC, значение поля provider нужно изменить на "rbac". В моем случае, соответственно, нужно было поменять rbac обратно на simple. Вероятно, где-то я ранее нахимичил с правами.

Более подробно в доках: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/RBAC

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам просто нужно было добавить *user.*

После установки сервера нужно запустить скрипт **add_user.sh** в папке **wildfly/bin.**

Дальше нужно следовать инструкциям и создать *user* под которым вы сможете заходить в админскую панель.